# Increment string(numbers) to total and print

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that i need to total by certain numbers in a string. I have received help to get this far the the answers have been great. I am new to python.
My sample csv file is such:

```
header row
date,ttp_ws_sm_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,117
date,ttp_ws_sm_001_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,31
date,ttp_ws_sm_045_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,145
date,ttp_ws_sm_045_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,55
date,ttp_ws_sm_057_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,98
date,ttpv1_001_, , , , , , , , , , , ,67
date,ttpv1_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,67*
```

My code works to just get all the 001 into one line as a total when print.
I need to get all the different codes like 001, 045, 002, etc so I can print out all the totals per number.

```
import csv
import sys
import os

def main():
    total = 0
    source = '\\\\Isfs\\data$\\GIS Carto\TTP_Draw_Count' 
    with open(os.path.join(source, 'TTP_13_08.csv'), 'r') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f)
       club_num = str(int('001') + 1

       for row in rows:
            try:
                t = row[1].split('_')
            except IndexError:
                continue
            if len(t) >= 4 and t[3] == (club_num) or \
            len(t) >= 2 and t[1] == (club_num):
                total += int(row[13])
            club_num = int(club_num + 1)
    print (str(club_num) + '\t' + str(total))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If i take out the club_num it will give a nice result

```
Club 001    148
```

what i need is

```
club 001   148
club 002   some number
club 045   200
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract your club numbers via regexp and collect results into `defaultdict(int)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import re
import os

def main():
    result = defaultdict(int)
    regexp = re.compile('ttp_ws_sm_(\d+)_')

    source = '\\\\Isfs\\data$\\GIS Carto\TTP_Draw_Count' 
    with open(os.path.join(source, 'TTP_13_08.csv'), 'r') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f)

        for row in rows:
            match = regexp.search(row[1])
            if match:
                result[match.group(1)] += int(row[13])

    for key, value in result.iteritems():
        print "club %s %s" % (key, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

prints:

```
club 001 148
club 057 98
club 045 200
```

Comment: Wehn I modified my code like above I get a NameError: global name 'default' is not defined.

Comment: Have you imported `defaultdict`? `from collections import defaultdict`

Comment: Yes I have imported as alecxe askes. I am using python 2.7.

Comment: This works, however, the print out isn't like I need in my question. I need to have the print look like
club 001   148
club 045   200

Comment: Thank you. This is almost were I need to be. I am much further along.